# Display object of different type in a recyclerview

Tags: android, java-8, android-recyclerview

I have this json that come from a search result, how to display it in a recyclerview? I want to display the look, clothingItem, events, tags. The search can return any amount of these item, I want to display them. Should I convert each of these item into a common class? Or how to create different adapter for each of these object? I'm confuse.

```
{
results: {
clothing_items: [
{
id: 422,
created_at: "2020-01-20 11:23:10 -0500",
image: "",
last_event_date: null,
name: "desk",
thumbnail: "",
type_of: "accessories"
 }
],
events: [
{
  id: 157,
 date: "2020-01-14 09:53:00 -0500",
 image: null,
 name: ""
}
],
looks: [

],
tags: [
 {
id: 97,
created_at: "2020-01-20 10:46:12 -0500",
title: "greatest person"
 }
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- to make your code readable and type safe and my be scale in any time you should make every one in sperated class and using gson in retrofit help you to match json with class without any additional code

2- some library like volley help you to decode json object so if you want to get headache you can use it

3- you will need 3 viewHolde or make it generic ViewHolder and in binding cast them according to flag you pass to constractor or use instanceof keyword in java

4- if they not use the same design you will need to use different design layout and in inflation for view will change according to flag path to constractor of adapter

5- you can put all attribute in one class but not prefered it will make you lose Type Safe

Comment: I'm using gson with retrofit.

Comment: so make sperated class for each one and if you get problem i will help you